# Situación con datetimepicker

Tags: fullcalendar, datetimepicker

Estoy utilizando un fullcalendar para una agenda, al crear los eventos me guarda las fechas de inicio y fin con este formato 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'  solo que lo que corresponde a las horas, minutos y segundos solo agrega 00:00:00 de entrada esto no me representa ningún problema.

La situacion se complica un poco al utilizar un datetimepicker ya que en su forma nativa:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#startEdit").datetimepicker({
        language: 'es',
        startDate:new Date(),
        format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        timepicker:false,
        //pickTime: false
    });
```

al momento de seleccionar la fecha de manera automática me esta tomando la hora, minuto y segundos del sistema justo cuando haces clic para seleccionar una nueva fecha, y yo quisiera que no me agregara este dato , salvo que el usuario a través de la interfaz el fuera el que hiciera o modificara la hora.

Intente hacer lo siguiente

```
$("#startEdit").datetimepicker({
    language: 'es',
    startDate:new Date(),
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00",
    //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
    timepicker:false,
    //pickTime: false
});
```

Que efectivamente me coloca las horas,minutos y segundos en 00:00:00 pero resulta que al querer editar estos valores desde la interfaz del usuario( calendario) no toma ningún valor.  Y yo solo quisiera que de manera natural me cargue las horas, minutos y segundos de esta manera 00:00:00 y solo que el usuario quiera añadir una hora y minutos, estos se carguen al momento de utilizar los controles destinado para ello,  para posteriormente guardar en la base de datos.   Alguna idea de como se podría hacer esto.   Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿Y que datetimepicker es?  Es que he visto muchos distintos, es para saber cual estas usando para no confundirnos

Comment: Hola @masterguru esta basado en boostrap esta es la cabecera: Version 3.0.0
=========================================================
bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
=========================================================
The MIT License (MIT)

Comment: Esa versión 3 ya no tiene ni documentación. Ahora van por la 6. Poco puedo ayudarte así, lo siento. Suerte!

Comment: Ok , gracias que tengas un Buen día!!.

Comment: De nada, lo siento.. veo que la 3.0.0 es del 12 Mar 2014, ejem... quizas debas replantearte actualizarla para no tener otros problemas más adelante.  https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus/releases/tag/v3.0.0

Comment: Gracias @masterguru ya he revisado alguna documentacion pero no logro encontrar lo que necesito,  pues a darle...  Saludos